# Firestore document Set with mergeFields when creating a document does not work as expected

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am saving a documemnt with a batch write like so:

```
batch.set(admin.firestore().collection('suuntoAppWorkoutQueue').doc(generateIDFromParts([serviceToken.userName, payload.workoutKey])), <QueueItemInterface>{
          userName: serviceToken.userName,
          workoutID: payload.workoutKey,
          retryCount: 0,
          processed: false, 
        }, {mergeFields: ['retryCount']});
```

According to the docs:

> Changes the behavior of set() calls to only **replace** the specified field paths. Any field path that is not specified is ignored and remains untouched.

Above it is said that it will only replace.

However, when I write a new document, eg the doc ID is does not exist the `mergeFields` only writes the `retryCount` field.

Is that by design?

Shouldn't then be saying:

> Changes the behavior of set() calls to only **write**

Instead of:

> > Changes the behavior of set() calls to only **replace**

Comment: I came across a similar requirement. Found any luck with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can follow your argumentation about write/replace. I did not check the behavior myself, but if the field is written if the document does not exist 'write' or 'update' would be a better suited description of the behavior than replace as there is nothing to be replaced in the first place.

If you only want to update the field if the document already exists, you can use a transaction to do so. You can use the transaction to get the latest version of the document, check if it exists and if so update it.

```
let data = {
    userName: serviceToken.userName,
    workoutID: payload.workoutKey,
    retryCount: 0,
    processed: false, 
}

let db = admin.firestore()
let documentReference = db.collection('suuntoAppWorkoutQueue').doc(...)
db.runTransaction((transaction) =>
  transaction.get(documentRef).then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      return t.update(documentRef, {retryCount: data.retryCount});
    } else {
      return t.set(documentRef, data);
    }
  }
).then(...).catch(...)
```

Transactions also have the benefit to be atomic. If the value on the server has changed since you fetched it, the transaction will fail. Firestore actually will re-run your code in this case to re-attempt the update. This eliminates race conditions.

Comment: I want to update x field if the document exists, else just write what I have there.
Unfortunately with `mergeFields` when writing a new document it only still writes the mergeFields not any of the rest. Thus my question and why one would use this.

Comment: I updated the code sample above to for your case. Hope that helps!
One possible scenario to use mergeFields is with strongly typed languages such as Java. If you have two different apps writing to the same document and both have different or one has an outdated model class it might accidentally delete data from the document during an update. Merging allows to update the portion of the document you know about and just leave the rest as is (if it exists). I had this while adding a field to an app and older versions deleted it on every update. Merging prevents that. There might be more scenarios

Comment: Its a good answer, dont get me wrong, and since the bounty expires you get it pal. 
However, to be honest, its not intuitive what firebase has. 
The reason why I don't want to read first is due to high load of the documents butr at least I can use it as a workarround for now.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, it's not intuitive. You can try reaching out to the Firebase folks, they are very responsive.

Comment: Did that opened an issue , will try again via the support no worries. 
Thanks again! 
I leave this answer open just in case. I will remember in a few to validate yours .

Comment: @JimmyKane I encounter exactly the same issue when using firestore with flutter. I suppose the set method will totally ignore the SetOptions when a document is not exist.

Comment: @JimmyKane After I look for a while for the issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1834 it seems that the SDK will never read the existing record from the database (Because it cause one extra read) and perform the merge. It says in a batch operation it will merge the existing document if it exist.